# how to find menu ul tag position in magento

Tags: html, magento-1.8

It looks silly. I am new to this....

Please visit the link : http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/

If you inspect element on menu=> on "home", you can see

```
<div class="nav-container">

<script type="text/javascript"/><script>

<ul id="nav">  // This line I want to delete
```

I want to Delete the id "nav". 
Where is that  tag in code?
In which folder, which file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many option to do this, what i recommend you have to login in your magento dashboard then go to System->configuration->then select developer from left panel.

Then you will find there one debug tag click on there then select yes to template path hints.

Then Save your setting.

Now you open your site you will see there path of your menu file, from which file is this coming.

Then you simply traverse to that path using your FTP connection.

then change what you want.

There are some extension which are provide this feature through some get parameter like

[Extension to find magento template path](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I enabled DEBUG tag to "yes" .  I did't got ,how to find path? where i can see the path? Is using inspect element or any other way ?

Comment: By default menu is coming from header.phtml file in your template theme folder, you can go directly there and find the element and you can do what ever you want. Or you can use the extenaion which is mansion above.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the code in the following path:

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\yourtheme\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml

or

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml

To change the css

```
#nav > li {
width: 20%;
}
#nav > ul {
float: none;
margin: 0;
width: 96.2%;
}
```

Comment: Send me the topmenu.phtml file